# Called 'load' without the :safe option -- defaulting to safe mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

How do I get rid of this warning/error, when I start rails.

Called 'load' without the :safe option -- defaulting to safe mode.

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Called 'load' without the :safe option -- defaulting to safe mode.
>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to  1024 
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3001, CTRL+C to stop
```

Comment: which version of ruby are you using?

Comment: I am using ruby 2.0.0

Comment: Can someone provide some insights on this?

Answer (score 5):

That message comes from the [safe_yaml](https://github.com/dtao/safe_yaml) gem when some code invokes the YAML.load method without the safe_yaml gem being configured.

There are several options for getting rid of the warning.

1. Configure safe_yaml to suppress warnings:

   ```
   SafeYAML::OPTIONS[:suppress_warnings] = true
   ```
2. Configure safe_yaml's default mode explicitly:

   ```
   SafeYAML::OPTIONS[:default_mode] = :safe
   ```
3. If you're the one calling YAML.load, explicitly pass the :safe option when calling YAML.load or call YAML.safe_load/YAML.unsafe_load instead:

   ```
   YAML.load(yaml, :safe => true)
   YAML.load(yaml, :safe => false)
   YAML.safe_load(yaml)
   YAML.unsafe_load(yaml)
   ```